# How can i create object of 'Todo' model in b.js which is in another javascript file a.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

in a.js

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
    defaults: {
        _id: '',
        label: '',
    },
});
```

in b.js

```
$(function(){
    $.getScript("/js/a.js");
    var obj = new Todo();
});
```

It is giving error Problem is not a constructor

Comment: don't you need `new Todo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `getScript` is an asynchronous call so `Todo` is not immediately available, to resolve the issue call the `ToDo` constructor in the `getScript` success callback:

```
$(function(){
    $.getScript("/js/a.js", function() {
        var obj = new Todo();
    });
});
```